# How to get the current time stamp in PIG

Tags: java, hadoop, scripting, apache-pig

I have a query with respect to a PIG script that I am writing.

How can I get the current Unix Time Stamp in PIG script.?
Do I need any UDF for the purpose.. or can PIG provide me the currnet time stamp ?

Kindly advice me.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I am pointing two solutions

first one:

use CurrentTime(),convert it to ToUnixTime() for need to get timestamp.

```
Ex:
 X = load "xx"  .........  ;

 X1 = FOREACH X GENERATE ToUnixTime(CurrentTime())
```

second one:

Passing from command line as a parameter.

```
   pig  -f  myscript.pig --param timestamp=$(date +%s)

   ----in myscript.pig ----

     %declare time '$timestamp ';

     X1 = FOREACH X GENERATE '$time' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use a UDF. Good news is that it ships with Pig. It's called `CurrentTime`. Take a look at the [docs page here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#datetime-functions) for all the built-in functions.