# How to get EPOCH time in PIG?

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-pig, epoch

I am completely new to pig.
Started to learn on my own and trying to know PIG.
Can anyone please suggest me to get the **current system epoch time using pig** by reading a words.txt file which having words.

I need the output as

```
word1_1234567890 word2_1234567890 word3_1234567890
```

And **how can we call the shell script in PIG script**

Because I have already written the Shell script.

Any Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Mohan.v

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206808/how-to-get-the-current-time-stamp-in-pig

Comment: Some what. it converts system time to epoch time.fine.                                        But i need to get as word_epochtime.How can i get that.                                                    Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CONCAT to combine your word with the epochtime.You can get the epochtime using ToUnixTime()

```
A = LOAD 'words.txt' AS (word:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(A.word,'_'),(chararray)ToUnixTime(CurrentTime());
DUMP B;
```

Let's say your shell script is names test.sh

```
%declare my_shell_script 'test.sh'
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (f1:int,f2:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE '$my_shell_script';
```

If your shell script has parameter say param1

```
%declare my_shell_script 'test.sh $param1'
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (f1:int,f2:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE '$my_shell_script';
```

Comment: thank you inquisitive_mind.                                                                                         how can i read the words.txt file contains words..and by reading each word from that words.txt file i should get the epoch time as                                                 word1_epochtime                                                                                                   word2_epochtime                                                                                                     Can you suggest me on this

Comment: Please be specific in asking your questions. Stackoverflow is not a place where you can outsource all your questions.Seems like there are 3 parts in your question.Please edit your question to include all the details in your question rather than asking users to keep helping with additional parts in your task.

Comment: Sorry inquisitive_mind.                                                                                                   It will not repeat again.                                                                                              By the way thanks for the reply and your precious time.